# Firewall blocks localhost but only if it's turned on

Tags: networking, firewall, localhost, xampp, comodo-firewall

I run XAMPP server on my Windows XP. If I try to access to `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` it gives me this error:

> Could not connect to remote server

This only occurs if my Comodo firewall is turned on. I turned off the firewall and everything worked perfectly. The problem isn't about the Comodo Defense+ because it is still on. The problem must be with the firewall, because if I trun it off everything is ok.

I still can ping both `http://localhost` and `http://127.0.0.1` even if the firewall is turned on.

I tried to set `http://127.0.0.1` fully enabled both in the Aplication Rules and Global Rules tab in the firewalls Network Security Policies settings, but didn't changed anything.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution:

I blocked some time wasting sites in the `.hosts` file like this:

> 127.0.0.1       example.com     www.example.com

For "double protection" I also blocked `example.com` in the Comodo firewall's Blocked Zones tab in the Network Security Policies settings, thus the firewall blocked `example.com` that was redirected to `127.0.0.1` in the same time. After deleting the blocked addresses from the Blocked Zones tab everything works correctly even if the firewall is turned on.

---

I neither blocked directly `localhost` in the `.hosts` file, nor in the firewall. However indirectly I blocked `localhost` in the firewall because I blocked sites that were redirected to `localhost`. If I disabled the firewall only the redirections were active, so eg. if I typed `example.com` it redirected to my local server. When the firewall (and the blocks too) were enabled then they blocked `localhost` thought the blocked `example.com`.

The problem was not in the settings of the .hosts file and (kinda) not in the blocks in the firewall because I used both of them frequently. I just didn't thought they will affect eachother. In addition you only notice this conflict in some specific cases like mine: you have a server, and want to acces it through `localhost`.